# How do I check if an A tag is wrapping around an IMG element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an array of dom elements:

```
var arr = $("a");
```

How would you check, within a for loop, whether this A tag is wrapping around an IMG element?

```
arr[i].has("img")
```

Doesn't work because it is taking an array element.

Comment: And does the `$` represent jQuery? If so, you're missing a tag

Comment: Oh well -> `arr.eq(i).has('img')` seeing as you don't have an array, but a collection of elements

Comment: you could also avoid the for loop by using `$('a').filter(':has(img)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jQuery selector returns an array which is overloaded with a number of functions. By taking just one of those indexes you lose those functions. To work around this do:

```
  $(arr[i]).has("img")
```

This now results in an array that has jQuery's functions, but only contains the item you passed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = $('a');
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 if ( $(arr[i]).find('img').length>0 ) {
   console.log('has img');
  } else {
   console.log('has no img');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>
  <img/>
</a>

<a></a>
```